# C++ Storing Array in Separate File

Tags: c++, arrays, header-files

I am working on a c++ program in which I have to pass an array to multiple sorting functions and compare the running times of the functions.  For example, I have an array with 100 elements containing random numbers from 1 to 10.  I have a bubble sort, merge sort, and quick sort function, and I have to pass the array to each function.  However when I pass the array, the first sorting function changes the original array so that when it is passed to the next function it is already sorted.  This is expected, but I was wondering how I would store this array in a separate file, perhaps a header file, to keep the original array unsorted for each function call.

Here is a layout of my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//void bubblesort, mergesort, quicksort function prototypes

int main()
{
    int a[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        a[i] = rand() % 10 + 1;
    bubblesort(a);
    mergesort(a);
    quicksort(a);
    return 0;
}

//void bubblesort, mergesort, quicksort function definitions
```

This code is obviously just a layout and the sorting functions aren't relevant for this question other than the fact that a call to a sorting function changes the original array.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just copy the array to a new array variable each time you want to sort. No need to save it to a file. Check out `memcpy()` or write a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need files for this.  Even though usual file systems on operating systems these days are rather nicely mapped to memory (in many cases this will be their cache) with delayed swapping to disk, interacting with the file system may make your code much more inefficient since you are writing to the disk.

Since you tagged this question with C++ I will answer this question the C++ way (or at least the C++ standard library way).  What you want is to make a copy of the array when you pass it to the functions.  At the moment you are passing in the raw address of the array so you are not making any copies (only possibly a copy of the pointer).  This process is made easy if you use [vectors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).  So the program could be

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

// The declarations would just need to change to this, I am assuming 
// they print to stdout
void bubblesort(vector<int> vec);
void mergesort(vector<int> vec);
void quicksort(vector<int> vec);

int main()
{
    vector<int> a;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        a.push_back(rand() % 10 + 1);
    bubblesort(a);
    mergesort(a);
    quicksort(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Here the vectors will be passed in by value so the vector that the function accesses is a copy of the original. The thing with vectors is that they are much more flexible and should usually be preferred over arrays in most high level programming scenarios.

If however your application demanded a use of low level arrays you could use memcpy to achieve this copying effect.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

//void bubblesort, mergesort, quicksort function prototypes

int main()
{
    int a[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        a[i] = rand() % 10 + 1);

    int for_bubble_sort[100];
    memcpy(for_bubble_sort, a, 100);
    bubblesort(for_bubble_sort);

    int for_merge_sort[100];
    memcpy(for_merge_sort, a, 100);
    mergesort(for_merge_sort);

    int for_quick_sort[100];
    memcpy(for_quick_sort, a, 100);
    quicksort(for_quick_sort);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: your second code sample still has `vector` in the function declarations

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should make an another array. Copy the contents of original array to this one using `memcpy()` or use a loop.

Answer (score -2):

You can declare your array as `const` so it preserves it initial value and the functions don't change it.